# How to close contextmenu when mouse leaves it

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I'm using [jquery-ui-contextmenu](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu). The menu stays opened until a mouse click is done elsewhere. I want the menu to close when the mouse leaves it. I tried:

```
blur: function(event, ui) {
    $("#tree").contextmenu("close");
},
```

but the menu is closed as the mouve leaves the first menu item, so other items can never be selected.
It looks like a very simple need, does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: there seems to be many contextmenu plugins. Which one are you using..?

Comment: @T J I am using this one : https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu